# Errors LNK1120 and LNK2019 with third party dll library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, dllimport

I'm trying to get the data flow from a laser sensor with its own SDK tools, which has four files.

> EthernetScanner.dll
>
> EthernerScanner.lib
>
> EthernetScannerSDK.h
>
> EthernetScannerSDKDefine.h

There are always two errors here:

> Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EthernetScanner_Connect@12 referenced in function _wmain C:\Users\gearg\Desktop\Wenglor_SDK_test\test_18_12_19\test_18_12_19\test_18_12_19.obj
>
> Error 2 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals C:\Users\gearg\Desktop\Wenglor_SDK_test\test_18_12_19\Debug\test_18_12_19.exe 1

My simple test code is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

#include "EthernetScannerSDKDefine.h"
#include "EthernetScannerSDK.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    void* scanner;
    char IP[32] = "192.168.001.250";
    char Port[32] = "32001";
    scanner = EthernetScanner_Connect(IP, Port, 1000);

    return 0;
}
```

I have already put the files in project folder and set all include, additional library and dependencies.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Make absolutely certain you added all of the libraries and library paths and then check for typos.

Comment: Also make certain the libraries are for the correct version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Also you can't mix 32 and 64 bit. if the library is 32 bit your application must be 32 bit. Same goes for 64 bit.

Comment: Visual Studio also has independent settings for each configuration. If you added settings in Release mode it won't apply to Debug unless you selected multiple configurations (and Debug was in the selection).

Comment: @drescherjm I change to Release mode, it works! Thanks a lot! :)